# MySql. UPDATE if value exists - else INSERT (for not primary and not unique value)

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have `my_table` with `column1` column.
If there are rows with `column1='old'` I want to update those rows.
Else, I want to insert a new row.

Something like this:

```
IF(
   (EXISTS(
      SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column1='old'
       )),
   (UPDATE my_table SET column1='new' WHERE column1='old'),
   (INSERT INTO my_table (column1) VALUES ('new') )
     )
```

I use `MySql` so I cannot use `IF` on the beginning of query.

**`column1` is not unique and not primary.** So I cannot use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or `REPLACE`

Comment: If you cannot add a unique index and since triggers cannot action the table which fired the trigger then you don't have much choice other that to write a procedure in mysql or code for it in your app(if you have one).

Comment: @P.Salmon I did not expect such stiffness from MySql :)  Thank you very much, anyway.